# MySQL indexing char(1) columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a complex query that  I look for optimization,
I read most of the documentation on MySQL indexing .. but in this case I`m not sure 
what to do:

Data structure:

```
-- please, don't comment on the field types and names, it is outsourced project.

CREATE TABLE items(
  record_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  solid CHAR(1) NOT NULL, -- only 'Y','N' values
  optional CHAR(1) NULL, -- only 'Y','N', NULL values
  data TEXT
 );
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE record_id != 88
AND solid = 'Y'
AND optional !='N'  -- 'Y' OR NULL
```

Of course there are extra joins and related data, but this are the biggest filters.

In the scenario of:
 - 200 000+ records,
 - 10% (from all) with `solid` = 'Y',
 - 10% (from all) with `optional` !='N',

What would be good index for this query ?
or more precisely:

- does the first check record != 88 slows they query in any way ?
  (it only eleminates one result...?)
- which is faster  (`optional` !='N') or ( 'optional' = 'Y' OR 'optional' iS NULL )
  as mentioned above  `optional` = 'N' are 10% of the total count.
- is there anything special for indexing a CHAR(1) column with only 2 possible values?
- can I use this index (record_id, solid, optional)?
- can I create a index for specific value (solid = 'Y', optional !='N')?

As @Jack requested, current **EXPLAIN** result (out of 30 000 total rows with 20 results):

```
+-------------+-------+--------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| select_type | type  | possible_key |   key   | key_len | ref  | rows  |    Extra    |
+-------------+-------+--------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| PRIMARY     | range | PRIMARY      | PRIMARY |       4 | NULL | 16228 | Using where |
+-------------+-------+--------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: FYI, `optional != 'N'` is not the same as `'Y' OR NULL`. `NULL` is special, and fails both `=` and `!=` tests.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` say? That would be the first to check.

Comment: @Jack not really because I have small dataset for now, and there is only PK index.

Comment: You can simulate a bigger data set couldn't you? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question.  Overall, your query has an estimated selectivity of about 1%.  So, if 100 records fit on a page, then you would assume that each page would still have to be read, even with the index.  Because a record is so small (depending on `data` that is), this is quite likely.  From that perspective, an index is not worth it.

An index would be worth it under the following circumstances.  The first is when the index is a covering index, meaning that you can satisfy the query with all the columns in the index.  For example:

```
select count(*)
FROM items
WHERE record_id != 88 AND solid = 'Y' AND optional !='N'  -- 'Y' OR NULL
```

Where the index is on `solid, optional, record_id`.  The query doesn't need to go back to the original data pages.

Another case would be when the index is a primary (or clustered) index.  The data is stored in that order, so fetching a limited number of results would reduce the read overhead of the query.  The downside to this is that updates and inserts are more expensive, because data actually has to move.

My best guess in your case is that an index would not be useful, unless `data` is quite large (in the kilobyte range).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put indexes on the columns that will do the most discrimination. Usually indexing a binary column is not very helpful, if the database is about evenly split between the values. But if the value you often search for only appears 10% of the time, it can be a useful index.

If any of the columns are indexed, they will usually be checked before doing any other `WHERE` processing. The order that you put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause is not generally relevant. You can use `EXPLAIN` to find out which indexes a query uses.